# Python - How to access the current state of the range-type object returned by range()?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

In Python 3, if I'm not mistaken, the range-type object created by range() generates numbers on-demand for a for-loop, in a way that is somewhat similar to a generator.

I'm wondering if it is possible to access the current value that the range-object is giving to the for-loop (I'm running a thread elsewhere to keep track of progress in a for loop). For example, in:

```
range_obj = range(0, 10000)
for i in range_obj:
    print(i)
```

Let's say I'm on the 100th iteration in which "99" will be printed, and I only have access to the variable `range_obj`. Is there some method or variable I can call on with `range_obj` (such as in the manner of `range_obj.X`) to get the number "99"? If not a method or variable, Is there any possible way for me to access this number "99" from outside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
class MyRange:

    def __init__(self, *params):
        self.range_iterator = iter(range(*params))
        self.sentinel = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.sentinel = next(self.range_iterator)
        return self.sentinel

r = MyRange(0, 1000)

for i in r:
    print(r.sentinel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Range objects carry no iteration state. There's a common misconception that `range` returns a generator, but range objects are lazy, immutable *sequences*, not generators. You can't determine the state of an iteration over a range by looking at the range.